# How do I write a query to find a missing number?

Tags: mysql, sql, missing-data

I need to write a query to find out a set of missing numbers in a given 
sequence.

For example, a Column in a table has the following data:

```
Col1  
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
10
```

Here I need to write a query to find out the missing numbers and list it like this:

```
Col1 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I tried this

```
select l.IDBANK + 1 as start
from _bank as l
  left outer join _bank as r on l.IDBANK + 1 = r.IDBANK
where r.IDBANK is null
ORDER by 1
```

However, it shows just the first missing number in the list. How can I fix it?

Comment: do you want to grab the data, lookup, and fill in the column with stuff that is missing?

Comment: can you explain little bit.. you need missing numbers or all the numbers with the missing one ? .. and post what you tryed

Comment: *"I need to write a query..."* - You mean *"I need **you** to write a query..."*

Comment: `select min(col1) min, max(col1) max from table` and then in php `range($row['min'], $row['max'])`

Comment: SO is not a volunteer freelance group. Try something! if it fails, THEN come to use for help with an example of what you tried.

Comment: @SaggingRufus Apparently it is. :-(

Comment: @Strawberry :o NOOOOOOOOO

Comment: I need the numbers with the missing one

Comment: so............... none of the answers below worked? Yes? no? did you not let them know if it did or not? you asked for help, you got it. Now and as the saying goes, *"the ball is in your court"*.

Comment: No it not working for me cuz I want to display all the number including the missing one

Comment: You're actually comparing against the same table (_bank), with some weird comparison method, matching l.Id with r.Id+1, which makes it normal that you get only one Id not being matched..

Comment: I didn't particularly like your death threat earlier in your question, which I might add, saved the entire conversation and flagged to the moderators. Seeing the amount of reopen votes right now, is an insult to the community, after seeing the way you talk to people. The moderators deemed my flag as helpful. Your days may be numbered on Stack, so keep a civil tongue. Your telling me *"@ Fred -ii I don't know you but I will find you and I will kill you –  user487160"* was uncalled for. I see no reason for that, you are an unstable person that should seek professional help.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, there is a table `tbl_student`.

Table structure is like this:

[image]

So here are some missing roll numbers. If you want to get those roll numbers, then use this query:

```
// Database connection code here.
$i=0;
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_student");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $arr1[$i] = $row['roll'];
    $i++;
}
$arr2 = range(1,max($arr1));                                                    
$missing_numbers = array_diff($arr2,$arr1);
echo $missing_numbers;
```

I think this code will help you. Let me know please if this works.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you compare the data with two tables, lets say you have TableA and TableB and compare the matching and unmatching elements, you could do something like this:

```
select a.Col1, b.Col1 
from TableA a
left join TableB b on a.Col1 = b.Col1
```

and if you want to filter to show only items that are in TableA but not in TableB, you could add something like this:

```
where b.Col1 is not null
```

Comment: No it not working for me cuz I want to display all the number including the missing one

Comment: if you remove the where clause, you'll have all the numbers including the missing ones